# can't override checkout/total/default.phtml

Tags: checkout, layout, module, blocks, phtml

If I copy the file default.phtml from design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/ to my theme folder (design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/template/checkout/total/default.phtml) everything is fine, my changes are applied and I can see them on the front end. But what I want to do is different. I need this default.phtml file to be in a module that can be easily switched off when not needed; to achieve this I need to override the template file but here I got stuck because I couldn't find any reference to this template in checkout.xml

I also tried to modify the renderTotal() function in Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php (I copied the file in my module, didn't altered the core files) and I was able to apply some changes (I needed a colspan=2 instead of 1) but not all of them (the second cell is still being displayed when the colspan is set to 2 while I want only the cell with the colspan=2 to be shown). So the only way I can achieve what I need is to modify the default.phtml file.

So my question is: how can i override the dedault.phtml?

Answer (score 1):

The template is set in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Total/Default.php`. That's why you have to modify directly this file or to copy it in `app/code/local` and then to modify it or to overwrite it in your own custom module:

**config.xml**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <namespace_modulename>
            <class>Namespace_Modulename_Block</class>
        </namespace_modulename>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <total_default>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Total_Default</total_default>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**Namespace/Modulename/Block/Total/Default.php**

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Total_Default extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default
{
    protected $_template = 'checkout/total/your_default.phtml';
    protected $_store;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate($this->_template);
        $this->_store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    }
}
```

I didn't test it but it should be working. :)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to answer and I post it before finishing it.

Comment: I tried your method but if I try to have my template default.phtml in a subfolder inside the template folder (something like $_template = 'my_subfolder/checkout/total/my_default.phtml';), then my_default.phtml is no longer used and the frontend use magento phtml file

Comment: If you make your custom module, it's recommended to put the template files in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template`. Then the structure (and names of the dirs/files) doesn't matter (it's recommended to be `namespace/modulename/...`) but it will work each way. If your file is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/my_subfolder/checkout/total/my_default.phtml` and `$_template = 'my_subfolder/checkout/total/my_default.phtml';` - it should be working fine. In one word - there is no difference in how many subdirectories is the file. So if you make it right - please try to flush the cache.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it shows the 'frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/default.phtml' instead of my_default.phtml in frontend/base/default/template/my_subfolder/checkout/total

Comment: Now I researched the code more deeply. I tested my code and it's working. But this class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default` and this template `checkout/total/default.phtml` are only called in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php` -> `function _getTotalRenderer` and if it doesn't have `$config` which on a standard Magento installation has never happened. So are you sure that you want to rewrite this template? Please enable template path hints and block path hints and check for sure which are the files.

Comment: Thanks michael for all the time your spending on this, I turned on path hints as first thing in order to know which file to modify. In fact, if I modify the theme phtml file, my changes are correctly displayed. But I need to keep the modified phtml file in a subfolder of the template folder and that's where I got stuck, because I cannot find a way to make magento read my subfolder file instead of the normal one.

Comment: ok I figured it out.. for some reason, there is a tax block that has no template, so it falls back to the default.phtml.. I rewrote this block in my config.xml and set the template to default.phtml and now it works.. Still don't know the need of calling a tax block since there are no taxes involved, anyway I'm glad that it works now and thank you again for your help

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out. Please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: This config set up doesn't seem to be working for me in 1702